# Square div with fixed height using only CSS

Tags: html, css, height, width

Everything is in the title !

How can I do to make my div's width equals to its fixed height using CSS only ?

HTML Code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
.square{
    height:80%;
}
```

I know I can do the opposite (fixed width) using

```
.square{
   width : 20%;
   padding-top:20%
}
```

because padding-top is relative the width of the container.

I also know I can do it using simple JQuery but don't want to use javascript.

Thanks,

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: @john please edit your question remove the unnecessary tags

Answer (score 3):

Use vw unit :

```css
.square {
  background: #000;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: Vw unit is relative to the full window. My square's height is relatives to its container so I can't use Vw units I think

Comment: Oh ok, but then you need to recalculate the height on resize in javascript as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Viewport-percentage lengths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length) `vw`

```css
.square {
    background: #000;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want your div to be inside a .container which can be any size.  This is easy if the size of that .container is based on the viewport width.  I've created an example, below, which shows a block of square divs 2x2 inside of a .container.  The .container can be any size.  It is important the height and width of the container be based on viewport width.

```css
.container {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vw;
  margin: 0 5vw;
}
.container > div {
  width: 48%;
  height: 48%;
  margin: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.square1 {
  background: #aaa;
}
.square2 {
  background: #bbb;
}
.square3 {
  background: #ccc;
}
.square4 {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="square1"></div><div class="square2"></div><div class="square3"></div><div class="square4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use vw, try this out.

https://jsfiddle.net/zofoeLyL/2/

CSS

```
 .square{
    width:20%;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#005f95;
 }
 .square:before {    
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%; 
 }
```

HTML

```
 <div class="square">

 </div>
```

That will make the height always equal to whatever width % you decide to use.

Comment: It was asked for the other way ("fixed height" not width)